# Python BeautifulSoup - Expand all <div> issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and using BeautifulSoup to **scrape** data from: https://www.espn.com/mma/fightcenter

I am able to preform all my desired operations on the first fight listing since it is expanded by default. However, I run into issues in latter listings because the data I want is hidden down a tree of "div"s.

Is there a way to expands all of these trees on an entire web page when making the "soup"?

Here are the current lines of code I am using:

```
    headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
    headers.update({ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 
    Firefox/52.0'})
    espnurl = 'https://www.espn.com/mma/fightcenter'
    req = requests.get(espnurl, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html5lib')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @burns Did you find an answer to your question? I am also having the same problem and would like help.

Answer (score 0):

The soup variable you have above contains everything in the html doc. So actually, you are able to use all the 'collapsed' info that visually can't be seen on the screen. When scraping the web for data, it's a good idea to get as close as possible to what you want. For example, the code below will grab all the data for the main fights on that screen:

```
fights = soup.find_all('div', {"class" : "AccordionPanel"})
info = [fight.text for fight in fights]
print(info)
```

The fights variable above finds all the 'divs' that have that specific class name, which is a common identifier for the blocks of data you are looking for.
After that, you can just find all the text by looping through each block.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! But I still have an issue, I don't believe I explained it well initially. I am trying to take the fighters stats being: HEIGHT, WEIGHT, REACH, STANCE, SIG STR LPM, SIG STR ACC, TD AVG, TD ACC, and SUB AVG. As well as open each fighters full profile. However, even with your posted code I'm not able to find this information past the first fight listing. Instead I get the following: print(info[1]) --> Alexander Volkanovski21-1-0PPVMatch 2-220 / +185Max Holloway21-5-0. Which doesn't include the information I am looking for. Thanks again!